# Why would a group by return multiple groups with the same value?

Tags: mysql, group-by, aws-aurora

In the query

```sql
select pricing_date,count(*) 
from prices 
where pricing_date>='2022-12-01' 
group by pricing_date;
```

I receive results with multiple pricing_date groups of the same date:

```sql
+--------------+----------+
| pricing_date | count(*) |
|--------------+----------|
| 2022-12-01   | 40713    |
| 2022-12-05   | 1362     |
| 2022-12-06   | 448      |
| 2022-12-01   | 112      |
| 2022-12-05   | 790      |
| 2022-12-06   | 1007     |
| 2022-12-05   | 905      |
| 2022-12-06   | 225      |
```

etc., for 400 rows. Here's the result of `explain`:

```sql
explain format=json select pricing_date,count(*) from prices where pricing_date>='2022-12-01' group by pricing_date;
```

```json
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "397070.02"
    },
    "grouping_operation": {
      "using_filesort": false,
      "table": {
        "table_name": "prices",
        "access_type": "ALL",
        "possible_keys": [
          "pd_id",
          "id_pd"
        ],
        "rows_examined_per_scan": 520926311,
        "rows_produced_per_join": 1914444,
        "filtered": "0.37",
        "Using": "parallel query (1 columns, 1 filters, 0 exprs; 0 extra)",
        "cost_info": {
          "read_cost": "205625.62",
          "eval_cost": "191444.40",
          "prefix_cost": "397070.02",
          "data_read_per_join": "759M"
        },
        "used_columns": [
          "pricing_date"
        ],
        "attached_condition": "(`prices`.`pricing_date` >= DATE'2022-12-01')"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, if I change the date slightly the 2022-12-05 and 2022-12-06 dates appear to group as expected:

```sql
select pricing_date,count(*) 
from prices 
where pricing_date>='2022-12-05' 
group by pricing_date;
+--------------+----------+
| pricing_date | count(*) |
|--------------+----------|
| 2022-12-05   | 149752   |
| 2022-12-06   | 223728   |
+--------------+----------+
```

here's the result of explain:

```sql
explain select pricing_date,count(*) from prices where pricing_date>='2022-12-04' group by pricing_date;
+----+-------------+-----------------------+------------+-------+-----------------+---------+---------+--------+--------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table                 | partitions | type  | possible_keys   | key     | key_len | ref    | rows   | filtered | Extra                    |
|----+-------------+-----------------------+------------+-------+-----------------+---------+---------+--------+--------+----------+--------------------------|
| 1  | SIMPLE      | prices                | <null>     | range | pd_id,id_pd     | pd_id   | 4       | <null> | 976306 | 100.0    | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-----------------------+------------+-------+-----------------+---------+---------+--------+--------+----------+--------------------------+
```

Why doesn't the first query accurately group all the dates with the same date into the same group? I see that the second query uses a key as expected, but it doesn't seem like group by should fail on non-indexed results.

Here's the table schema:

```
+-----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table     | Create Table                                                       |
|-----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------|
|    prices | CREATE TABLE `prices` (                                            |
|           |   `pricing_date` date DEFAULT NULL,                                |
|           |   `id` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,                                   |
|           |   UNIQUE KEY `pd_id` (`pricing_date`,`id`),                        |
|           |   KEY `id_pd` (`id`,`pricing_date`)                                |
|           | ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
+-----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I'm using mysql 8.0.23 in AWS Aurora serverless v2 if that's relevant.

Comment: What if you execute this `select date(pricing_date) as new_pricing_date, count(*) from prices  where date(pricing_date)>='2022-12-01'  group by new_pricing_date;` , does it change the results ?

Comment: Looks like a bug.

Comment: @ErgestBasha that yields the correct results, but takes 200x longer than the same results using an index `select pricing_date,count(*) from prices force index (pd_id) where pricing_date>='2022-12-01' group by pricing_date;` (2.3 seconds vs 493 seconds)

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ a bug on Aurora I guess, never faced something similar on MySQL.

Comment: @enharmonic it seems that something is messing up the dates as the group by is working as expected when using the date function. I know the execution time would be higher because the date function doesn't use the index. Maybe you should file a bug on the Aurora side.

Comment: @ErgestBasha yeah, probably something wrong with the parallel plan, when gathering it is not aggregating results from different workers.

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` for the 'bad' one.

Comment: @RickJames edited to show explain results in json format

Comment: If Aurora has a way to turn off "parallel query", I recommend doing that.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by [Rick James](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/320689/why-would-a-group-by-return-multiple-groups-with-the-same-value?noredirect=1#comment625558_320689), [turning off Aurora's parallel query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-mysql-parallel-query.html#aurora-mysql-parallel-query-enabling) seems to solve the issue and give the expected results.